# Trying to export a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have three large matrices that I've converted to column vectors, and I'm trying to export them to a csv file.  My code looks like the following:

```
zi1994 <- as.matrix(read.csv("zi 1994.csv"), header=FALSE)
xi1994 <- as.matrix(read.csv("xi 1994.csv"), header=FALSE)
yi1994 <- as.matrix(read.csv("yi 1994.csv"), header=FALSE)
vectorzi <- as.vector(zi1994)
vectorxi <- as.vector(xi1994)
vectoryi <- as.vector(yi1994)
data.frame(vectorxi, vectoryi, vectorzi)
Cod1994 <- data.frame
```

I can't seem to write this data frame to a table for some reason. I've tried the usual methods:

```
write.table(Cod1994, file = "C:/Path/Cod1994.csv")
```

and

```
write.csv(Cod1994, file = "C:/Path/Cod1994.csv")
```

I always get the error

> "cannot coerce class 'function' into a data.frame."

This happens whether `<-` or `=` is used.  But the data frame looks fine.  What's going on?

Comment: You need to assign `data.frame(vectorxi, vectoryi, vectorzi)` to an object, for example `Cod1994 <- data.frame(vectorxi, vectoryi, vectorzi)`.  In the line `Cod1994 <- data.frame`, you try to assign the **function** `data.frame()` to an object, which is not allowed and generates the error message.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question, what you've done is made Cod1994 equal the function 'data.frame'. What you want is this:

```
foo <- data.frame(vectorxi,vectoryi,vectorzi)
write.csv(foo, 'foo.csv')
```